# WebBrowser File Explore Why is it Creating a New Folder on its own?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

This Program I been working on works great except for when a folder name contains any Symbol like "#" or "&" or any other symbol it will create a entirely new folder with  a % and some numbers behind it when i open the folder that was already there. But if i delete the Symbol it Works fine.[Photo Of The Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REgFX.jpg) 
I don't have any idea why it does it. When i open a folder it will read text files with properties and display them in the text Boxes but if it has a symbol it wont even do that. But If i delete the symbol and not change the property the Properties show the symbol so that is not the problem. If anyone has any idea on why it is doing this or need more information just let me know please.

Thank you

```
    //
    //START UP PROCCESS
    //

    private void JobViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        timer1.Start(); //CLOCK
        int BrowserVer, RegVal;

        // get the installed IE version
        using (WebBrowser Wb = new WebBrowser())
            BrowserVer = Wb.Version.Major;

        // set the appropriate IE version
        if (BrowserVer >= 11)
            RegVal = 11001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 10)
            RegVal = 10001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 9)
            RegVal = 9999;
        else if (BrowserVer == 8)
            RegVal = 8888;
        else
            RegVal = 7000;

        // set the actual key
        RegistryKey Key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
        Key.SetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe", RegVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        Key.Close();

        contextMenuStrip1.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new ColorTable());

    }
    //
    //OPEN PERSON'S FILE LOCATION
    //
    private void FLoc1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Chad");

    }
    private void FLoc2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Dan");
    }
    private void FLoc3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Erv");
    }
    private void FLoc4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Jacob");
    }
    private void FLoc5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Nate");
    }
    private void FLoc6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Miller");

    }
    private void FLoc7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Terry");

    }
    private void FLoc8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Kelley");
    }
    private void FLoc9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayJobs.Navigate(@"F:\Internal Jobs\Jobs\Jenny");
    }
private void DisplayJobs_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        JobPath.Text = DisplayJobs.Url.ToString();


    }
    private void JobPath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = JobPath.Text.Remove(0, 8);


        FilesMade();



        try
        {
            lblContact.Text = File.ReadAllText((@textBox1.Text + 
@"\Properties\Contact.txt"));
            lblJobName.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + 
@"\Properties\JobName.txt");
            lblBidDate.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + 
@"\Properties\BidDate.txt");
            lblEngineer.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + 
@"\Properties\Engineer.txt");
            lblTakeOff.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + 
@"\Properties\TakeOff.txt");
            lblReceived.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + 
@"\Properties\Received.txt");
            lblVendor.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + 
@"\Properties\Vendor.txt");
            //Specific Person Notes
            lblJDNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + 
@"\Properties\Notes\JDNotes.txt");
            lblNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\GNotes.txt");
            ChadNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\CNotes.txt");
            DanNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\DNotes.txt");
            ErvNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\ENotes.txt");
            NateNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\NNotes.txt");
            TerryMNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\TMNotes.txt");
            TerrySNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\TSNotes.txt");
            KelleyNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\KNotes.txt");
            JenNotes.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Notes\JenNotes.txt");
            lblPriorApp.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\PriorApp.txt");

            lblProject.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Project.txt");
            lblLocation.Text = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text + @"\Properties\Location.txt");
        }
        catch
        { }

        //Converts The Bid Date To Long Date
        try
        {


            DateTime convertedtime = DateTime.Parse(lblBidDate.Text);
            JobName.Text = lblJobName.Text;


            JobLocation.Text = lblLocation.Text;

            JobBidDate.Text = convertedtime.ToLongDateString();
        }
        catch { }

        if (Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + @"\Archive"))
        {
            JobName.Text = "";
            JobLocation.Text = "";
            JobBidDate.Text = "";
        }
    }
    private void JLCont_char(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " 
- " + lblJobName.Text))
        //     btnEdit.Enabled = false;
        if (Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " 
+ lblJobName.Text))
            NewJob.Enabled = true;
        if (Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\6-Emails"))
            NewJob.Enabled = true;
        if (Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\6-Emails"))
            btnEdit.Enabled = true;

    }

    //
    //CREATE A NEW JOB
    //
    private wbNewJob wbNwJob = new wbNewJob();
    private void NewJob_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + 
" - " + lblJobName.Text))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + 
lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text);



            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\0-Submittals"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\0-Submittals");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\0-Submittals" + "\\Properties"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\0-Submittals" + "\\Properties");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\0-Submittals" + "\\Properties\\Notes"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\0-Submittals" + "\\Properties\\Notes");

            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\1-Pricing"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\1-Pricing");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\1-Pricing" + "\\Properties"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\1-Pricing" + "\\Properties");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\1-Pricing" + "\\Properties\\Notes"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\1-Pricing" + "\\Properties\\Notes");

            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\2-Take Off"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\2-Take Off");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\2-Take Off" + "\\Properties"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\2-Take Off" + "\\Properties");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\2-Take Off" + "\\Properties\\Notes"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\2-Take Off" + "\\Properties\\Notes");

            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\3-Files"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\3-Files");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\3-Files" + "\\Properties"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\3-Files" + "\\Properties");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\3-Files" + "\\Properties\\Notes"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\3-Files" + "\\Properties\\Notes");

            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\4-Plans"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\4-Plans");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\4-Plans" + "\\Properties"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\4-Plans" + "\\Properties");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\4-Plans" + "\\Properties\\Notes"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\4-Plans" + "\\Properties\\Notes");

            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\5-Specs"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\5-Specs");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\5-Specs" + "\\Properties"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\5-Specs" + "\\Properties");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\5-Specs" + "\\Properties\\Notes"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\5-Specs" + "\\Properties\\Notes");

            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\6-Emails"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\6-Emails");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\6-Emails" + "\\Properties"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\6-Emails" + "\\Properties");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\6-Emails" + "\\Properties\\Notes"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\\6-Emails" + "\\Properties\\Notes");

            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\Properties"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + "\\Properties");
            if (!Directory.Exists(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\Notes"))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@textBox1.Text + "\\" + lblBidDate.Text + " - " + lblJobName.Text + @"\Properties\Notes");
        }
        catch
        { }
        try
        {
            PriceAllInOnePricingCreate();
            ExcelTakeOffCreate();
            CapsPricingCreate();
            WriteToPropertiesNJ();
            WriteToEmailsNJ();
            WriteToFilesNJ();
            WriteToPlansNJ();
            WriteToPricingNJ();
            WriteToTakeOffNJ();
            WriteToSubmittals();
            WriteToSpecsNJ();
        }
        catch { }





        try
        {
            wbNwJob.Show();

            wbNwJob.lblContact.Text = lblContact.Text;
            wbNwJob.lblJobName.Text = lblJobName.Text;
            wbNwJob.lblLocation.Text = lblLocation.Text;
            wbNwJob.lblBidDate.Text = lblBidDate.Text;
            wbNwJob.lblEngineer.Text = lblEngineer.Text;
            wbNwJob.lblPriorApp.Text = lblPriorApp.Text;
            wbNwJob.lblTakeOff.Text = lblTakeOff.Text;
            wbNwJob.lblProject.Text = lblProject.Text;
        }
        catch { }


    }
    //
    //EDIT AN EXISTING JOB
    //
    private void btnEdit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        try
        {
            WriteToPropertiesED();
            WriteToEmailsED();
            WriteToFilesED();
            WriteToPlansED();
            WriteToPricingED();
            WriteToTakeOffED();
            WriteToSubmittalsED();
            WriteToSpecsED();

        }
        finally { MessageBox.Show("The Job Has Been Saved"); }

    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you have now, and tell us where it fails

Comment: that is the thing it does'nt fail. It Literaly just makes a new folder and keeps on going. IF you look at the photo the first 2 folders are what it does the second folder was the one i had # before the 2

Comment: Same answer, show us the code. And I consider this behavior failing so...

Comment: Alright I updated it with the code. But its not a problem with writing to file because it still writes to the file the only thing i can see is that it would be something to do with folder naming with symbols.

Comment: People need to be able to reproduce your issue to fix it most of the times. Thats why they need code

Comment: That makes sense thank you for explaining

Comment: If I find some time (meeting now) I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Yes, %23 is the URL encoding for "#".  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Yeah is there any way to get around this? i mean if it was a text file i could just do if statement and say if its this = this type thing you know but idk how to do such a thing for a element of a web browser that isnt realy classified as a html document and is not really an element. Some times i feel i make things way to complicated for my own good.